# jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete field.

I want this autocomplete to retrieve the data from my controller (ObtenerOrdenesCompra).

However it doesn't even call the function on the controller.

```
$('#Asignacion_Movimiento_OrdenCompra').autocomplete({
    url: '/Asignaciones/ObtenerOrdenesCompra?Serial=' + $("#Asignacion_Movimiento_Material").val(),
    width: 300,
    max: 10,
    delay: 100,
    cacheLength: 1,
    scroll: false,
    highlight: false
});
```

If i take a look into the source code of my generated html, it shows:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Asignacion.Movimiento.OrdenCompra" id="Asignacion_Movimiento_OrdenCompra" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input input-validation-error">
```

Why is setting the autocomplete option off?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a copy paste error but you are missing `{` in autocomplete options object. If it doesn't fix, make sure that URL is working outside the plugin and see if there are any `404`.

**EDIT**

```
$('#Asignacion_Movimiento_OrdenCompra').autocomplete({
        url: '/Asignaciones/ObtenerOrdenesCompra',
        width: 300,
        extraParams: {'Serial', $("#Asignacion_Movimiento_Material").val()},
        max: 10,
        delay: 100,
        cacheLength: 1,
        scroll: false,
        highlight: false
    });
```

Also note that the value you entered in the text field always comes as `q` parameter.

Comment: The URL is woking... but the autocomplete isn't

Comment: You mean to say that the URL is also triggering fine and you are getting the response but not able to show in auto complete?

Comment: Ok, so it worked out... however I cannot pass parameters... I'm trying this: $('#Asignacion_Movimiento_OrdenCompra').autocomplete('/Asignaciones/ObtenerOrdenesCompra?Serial=' + $("#Asignacion_Movimiento_Material").val());
but the Serial parameter always get empty (altough $("#Asignacion_Movimiento_Material").val() is never empty)

Comment: You have to use `extraParams` attribute to send params